# Excel VBA - Do something after printing

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro assigned to a button which hides certain rows and columns from a sheet, then changes to that sheet and opens the print dialog.

I would like to be able to unhide all of those rows and columns again upon after the print dialog has exited, either by printing or cancelling.

I have briefly tested doing this by changing to the sheet, opening the print dialog, then displaying a message box. However the message box simply displays over the top of the print dialog.

```
newPlan.Sheets("Single_Plan").Activate
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")

MsgBox ("Print Complete")
```

How can I get the code to continue running once the dialog has closed?

Answer (score 2):

[Jaafar Tribak](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1101970-open-native-not-sheet-printpreview-print-preview-window-non-active-sheet-post5299490.html#post5299490) just posted a solution that worked for me in Excel 2019:

```
Option Explicit

#If  VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr
#Else 
    Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
#End  If

Sub Test()

    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PrintPreviewAndPrint"

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until FindWindowEx(Application.hwnd, 0, "FullpageUIHost", vbNullString) = 0

    'code after print preview window is closed (printed or canceled)
    MsgBox ("Print Complete")

End Sub
```

Comment: a complete success!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do that from that dialog. This works though:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrintPreview).Show
MsgBox "Now cleanup."
```

If you insist on using Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint") then try this setup.

In ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.OnTime Now, "AfterPrintCleanup"
End Sub
```

In a normal module:

```
Sub AfterPrintCleanup()
    'do your cleanup here
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately it opens different print preview window than PrintPreviewAndPrint command.

Comment: I've edited the answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works if user hit print button, if they simply closed preview window it will not execute the "cleanup" part

Comment: The problem is that there is no way to avoid this, the PrintPreviewAndPrint does not trigger the BeforePrint event if the user decides not to print, the old-school printpreview does trigger it. I can't think of a way to avoid this situation.